# Import and delete raw files in SAS

Tags: import, sas, proc

Is there a way where I can import a raw CSV file and on successful import the CSV file gets deleted on the go?
The first part would be easy:

```
proc import datafile = "<path>\<file>.csv"
out = test
dbms = csv replace;
run;
```

Comment: How do you define a successful import? Proc Import may successfuly  import a file but incorrectly classify a variable. If you're going to create something like this use a data step import and then delete the file if successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in method in SAS to delete the CSV file after import as part of the import.  You can certainly do it (assuming proper permissions) a few different ways.  For example:

```
filename test 'c:\temp\test.csv';

proc import file=test out=test dbms=csv replace;
run;

data _null_;
  rc=fdelete("test");
run;
```

You could wrap that in a macro if you wished.  You also could use `sysexec` or `x`.

Comment: Wouldn't you need a conditional execution based on _error_ most likely?

Comment: Sure, i'm not writing the entire code here: just showing the general concept.  A request to write the entire macro would be off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Just another take on this, you can give direct commands to the operating sytem using the `X <'command'>;` and I suppose it should be much faster

For example in UNIX

```
x "rm <path>\<file>.csv"
```

For example in Windows

```
x "del <path>\<file>.csv"
```